# Use zend framework to retrieve contacts from yahoo and hotmail

Tags: zend-framework, contacts, yahoo, hotmail

I found this link to retrieve contacts from gmail really helpful.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-phpgooglecontact/index.html

I like to simplicity of using directly the username and password to retrieve the contacts list.
I have searched the web but I can't find a similar solution for yahoo and hotmail. Do you know if and how it can be done?
I am aware of the oAuth library but I find this closer to my needs.

Answer (score 1):

This one is to retrieve contacts from yahoo.

http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/Contacts/Actually-getting-Contacts-after-jumping-through/1254438660000-91dbd95f-e129-3a22-8d24-58eb1d1082bc?msg=Reply posted successfully.